# WTP for eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, fedora, fedora12

I installed fedora 12 in my machine and got Eclipse installed as a pert of the fedora installation. But i am not getting the dynamic Web Project option since I don't have WTP installed in my eclipse. I am not able to find the exact link/package for my Galileo version. This is what i checked:

http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/projects.php

For the above link, I selected the **WTP Common Tools**  download link, it redirected me to this link:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/

From the above link, i selected the build release **3.4.0**, then i got this:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.4.0/R-3.4.0-20120612174739/

From here i am fairly confused what to download for getting the WTP enabled for my eclipse.

**Note:** I don't want any additional package to be installed unnecessarily. All i want is only **WTP**

Please provide me the exact link for the same so that i can proceed with it.

Regards,

Comment: You should be using the Galileo site at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo , or, better yet, update to the current version of Fedora (17) and Eclipse (Juno [Galileo was 2009?]).  With versions that old, any bugs you find, you'll have to keep.

Comment: try command `sudo yum search eclipse | grep wtp` and you will find what you want.